# Can't run android studio emulator

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator

I am new to android studio and I am trying to run the code on virtual devices but I keep getting the error `Emulator: glClear:466 GL err 0x502` .

When it tries to run, it launches the emulator, but stops where the "google logo" is and gives me the error mentioned above (`Emulator: glClear:466 GL err 0x502`)

Comment: clean install then start as admin

Comment: Had the same problem, this fix worked for me: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48061593/emulator-glclear466-gl-err-0x502

Comment: Thank you, worked also for me!

Answer (score 0):

this issues is solved in the version 27.0.5 of the emulator