# Error 0x502 Android Emulator

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator

I just started in Android Studio to display a map using mapbox, and when I launch the emulator, the map is not displayed but only the mapbox logo. And I have this error:

> 12:22 Emulator: android/android-emugl/host/libs/Translator/GLES_V2/GLESv2Imp.cpp:glUniformMatrix4fv:3400 error 0x502
>
> 12:22  Emulator: android/android-emugl/host/libs/Translator/GLES_V2/
>
> 12:22  Emulator: GLESv2Imp.cpp:glUniformMatrix4fv:3400 error 0x502
>
> 12:22  Emulator: android/android-emugl/host/libs/Translator/GLES_V2/GLESv2Imp.cpp:glUniform2fv:3303 error 0x502
>
> 12:22  Emulator: android/android-emugl/host/libs/Translator/GLES_V2/GLESv2Imp.cpp:glUniform1f:3268 error 0x502
>
> 12:22  Emulator: android/android-emugl/host/libs/Translator/GLES_V2/GLESv2Imp.cpp:glUniform1i:3282 error 0x502
>
> 12:22  Emulator: android/android-emugl/host/libs/Translator/GLES_V2/GLESv2Imp.cpp:glUniform1f:3268 error 0x502
>
> 12:22  Emulator: android/android-emugl/host/libs/Translator/GLES_V2/GLESv2Imp.cpp:glUniform4fv:3359 error 0x502
>
> 12:22  Emulator: android/android-emugl/host/libs/Translator/GLES_V2/GLESv2Imp.cpp:glUniform1f:3268 error 0x502
>
> 12:22  Emulator: android/android-emugl/host/libs/Translator/GLES_V2/GLESv2Imp.cpp:glUniform1i:3282 error 0x502

[Screen error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PZlnl.png)

I helped myself to this: [Emulator: glClear:466 GL err 0x502](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48061593/emulator-glclear466-gl-err-0x502)
That is, I reinstall Android Studio totally, and then I manually reinstall HAXM and Android Emulator in the SDK Tool.
I also launched in Android Studio administrator mode but without success.

Thanks for your help

Comment: Did you manage to find the solution for that ?

Answer (score 9):

I had the same problem as you.
If you take a look at the other answer in that thread (https://stackoverflow.com/a/48084829/3557075) you'll see that one solution is to change the *configuration on the virtual devices in the emulator under "Emulated Performance - Graphics"*.

This seems to fix the problem for me, despite the fact that the app lags as hell in the emulator.

Answer (score 3):

I solved the issue with these steps:
1. Open AVD Manager
2. Actions 
3 Wipe Data

Answer (score 0):

I just faced with this error. I simply changed the API to the higher version ( changed it from 27 to 29 ) and it just worked perfectly

Answer (score -3):

Try Creating An AVD With Application Level 25+.
& While Creating AVD Select The Graphics Type As - Automatic So that AVD Can Automatically Detect Ur Graphics Hardware.

Comment: I still have the same error that appears, here is what I put : https://i.stack.imgur.com/xCegx.png