# Android OpenGL_ES error in Emulator

Tags: android

I am testing an android application with **OpenGL** and the application is working well in real devices but when I start to test the application in emulator using **x86** and **x86_64** the **Event Log** in Android Studio has an error spam of like.

```
Emulator: android/android-emugl/host/libs/Translator/GLES_V2/GLESv2Imp.cpp:glUniform1i:3282 error 0x502
Emulator: android/android-emugl/host/libs/Translator/GLES_V2/GLESv2Imp.cpp:glBlendEquationSeparate:573 error 0x500
```

[image]

and the studio begins to unresponsive.

I am also doing this [Error 0x502 Android Emulator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48840825/error-0x502-android-emulator) and this [Emulator: glClear:466 GL err 0x502](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48061593/emulator-glclear466-gl-err-0x502/48084829#48084829)

Also I increased the size of my **HAXM** to 4096mb and AVD to 2048 still the error is there.

I also don't know if this error is normal in emulator or not.
Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Try to create AVD with 768MB RAM

Answer (score 0):

From the gl_base_types.h line 56, you can find the definition as following

`#define GL_INVALID_OPERATION              0x0502`

This error often refer to invalid operation on these specific GL calls. From the GLESv2Imp.cpp, it means that dispatcher class doesn't call the host gl libs api successfully.