# Emulator: glClear:469 GL err 0x502

Tags: android, android-studio

I am not sure if anyone out there experienced this error when launching from AVD: 
"Emulator: glClear:469 GL err 0x502"

The above error repeats a few many times and the mobile device (in my case Nexus 5x API23) starts flickering

I have tried may things, including reinstalling the entire Android Studio and updating the entire package again.
Many thanks

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48061593/emulator-glclear466-gl-err-0x502

Comment: Thanks Alex, the steps: 
    Change the Emulated Performance to Software - GLES 2.0 and increasing the RAM to 3044MB, does makes it to work. But have noticed that it is the hardware GLES 2.0 that seems to be the issue.