# Image not being initialized

Tags: java, android

I am makin a tic tac toe game. My circle image does not initialize and shows out of memory error.

It shows this in Run:
[image: Click here for image]

I tried using other image but it does not work.

My java code

```
btn1.setOnClickListener( new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            btn1.setEnabled( false );
            if (chance==0){
                box1=0;
                chance=1;
                btn1.setBackgroundResource( R.drawable.cross );
            }else{
                box1=1;
                chance=0;
                btn1.setBackgroundResource( R.drawable.circle );
            }

        }
    } );
    btn2.setOnClickListener( new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            btn2.setEnabled( false );
            if (chance==0){
                box2=0;
                chance=1;
                btn2.setBackgroundResource( R.drawable.cross );
            }else{
                box2=1;
                chance=0;
                btn2.setBackgroundResource( R.drawable.circle );
            }

        }
    } );
```

and so on for 9 buttons

Thanks in advance and hope this question is clear!.

Comment: How is this related to JavaScript?

Comment: I think this post will help you , https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48061593/emulator-glclear466-gl-err-0x502/48084829#48084829

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution:

> change the configuration on the virtual devices in the emulator under "Emulated Performance - Graphics" so they use Software GLES 1.1

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48084829)

---

**Note**: Try to make your code easier to read. Idea:

1. Don't use variables box1, box2 ..., make an `int[] box = new int[9];`
2. Use a class that `extends OnClickListener`

*Code:*

```
private class BoxClickListener implements View.OnClickListener {
    private final int index;

    public BoxClickListener(int index) {
        this.index = index;
    }

    @Override 
    public void onClick(View v) {
        v.setEnabled(false);
        if (chance == 0) {
            box[index] = 0;
            chance = 1;
            v.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.cross);
        } else {
            box[index] = 1;
            chance = 0;
            v.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.circle);
        }
    }
}
```

*How to apply it:*

```
btn1.setOnClickListener(new BoxClickListener(1));
btn2.setOnClickListener(new BoxClickListener(2));
...
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should resize image to smaller than
for example 128 * 128

Comment: it does not help