I can't run my flutter project on second time
Why can't I run my flutter project a second time, the first time I run it works, but the next time an error appears:
E/emuglGLESv2_enc( 6572): device/generic/goldfish-opengl/system/GLESv2_enc/GL2Encoder.cpp:s_glGetUniformLocation:2206 GL error 0x502

console pic
i haved try to update my sdk, but is not work

Does this solve your problem? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48061593/emulator-glclear466-gl-err-0x502/48084829#48084829
